# UILabel upon a few UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

Am I able to create a `UILabel` that is layouted upon many `UITableViewCell`s?

I'm trying to make something like (that is just one section of my `UITableView`, each section can have one or more rows):

```
    ---------------------------------------------
    | Multi-lined label    |     row1 values    |
    | with some useless    |     row2 values    |
    | text                 |     row3 values    |
    ---------------------------------------------
```

I managed to create a UILabel (in the first row of a section) that is multi-lined and is not clipping to bounds. That works really well (it was a bit tricky to count each sections row heights, but doable) besides one case: when I'm scrolling `UITableView` from bottom to top - `UITableView` renders last row (without UILabel) so it has "no evidence" of having `UILabel` (because it is maintained in the first row of section). Can I force some kind of relayouting first cell in section? I tried `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` with first row in each section whenever I layouted not first cell in section but it gave me layouting errors that I really do not understand. Or maybe there is another idea to do so?

-- EDITED
To be clear: I have a custom UITableViewCell with an IB view, it has a few labels that each row consist of and a label named labelName that I want to be "multi-lined" along rows in that section. LabelName.text is empty for each row besides first one in each section.

I am adding somescreenshots:

1. Good screenshot - when I am scrolling to bottom I'm getting proper effect:
   [image: good]
2. Bad screenshot - when I am scrolling up, UITableView renders last row of section firstly, and afterwards renders upper rows - that gives effect of cut label (because multi-line label is in the first row)
   [image: bad]

I am not sure if code here will add anything to question - it is rather simple and almost whole logic is in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath`. I can only present how do I create custom `UITableViewCell`:

```
CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[CustomTableViewCell reuseIdentifier]];
if (cell == nil) {    
    cell = [[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithOwner:self];
    cell.clipsToBounds = NO;
    cell.labelName.clipsToBounds = NO;
    cell.contentView.superview.clipsToBounds = NO;
}
```

-- EDIT 2

Here is most of the code:

```
- (void) reloadData
{
    NSUInteger index = 0;
    for (NSDictionary *object in self.list) {
        CGFloat height = [[object objectForKey:@"name"] sizeWithFont:self.labelFont constrainedToSize:self.labelSize].height;
        [self.labelHeights addObject:NSNumberFloat(ceilf(height))];
        index++;
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *object = [self.list objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    CGFloat height = [[self.labelHeights objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] floatValue];
    NSUInteger count = [[object objectForKey:@"list"] count];
    CGFloat cellHeight = 30.f;
    if((indexPath.row + 1) == count){
        cellHeight = MAX(8.f + height - 30.f * indexPath.row, 30.f);
    }
    return cellHeight;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.list count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[self.list objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"list"] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *person = [self.list objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSDictionary *object = [[person objectForKey:@"list"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[CustomTableViewCell reuseIdentifier]];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithOwner:self];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        cell.clipsToBounds = NO;
        cell.labelName.clipsToBounds = NO;
        [cell.contentView.superview setClipsToBounds:NO];
    }


    if(indexPath.row == 0){
        cell.labelName.text = [person objectForKey:@"name"];
        CGFloat height = [[self.labelHeights objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] floatValue];
        cell.labelName.numberOfLines = (int)(height / self.fontSizeHeight);
        cell.labelName.frame = CGRectChangeHeight(cell.labelName.frame, height);
    }
    else{
        cell.labelName.text = @"";
    }
    CGFloat cellHeight = [self tableView:self.tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.borderTop.hidden = YES;
    cell.borderBottom.hidden = YES;
    cell.borderBottomSmall.hidden = NO;
    if(indexPath.row == 0){
        cell.borderTop.hidden = NO;
    }
    if(indexPath.row + 1 == [[person objectForKey:@"list"] count]){
        cell.borderBottom.hidden = NO;
        cell.borderBottom.frame = CGRectChangeY(cell.borderBottom.frame, cellHeight - 1.f);
        cell.borderBottomSmall.hidden = YES;
    }

    cell.labelDate.text = [object objectForKey:@"date"];
    cell.labelPremium.text = [[object objectForKey:@"premium"];

    return cell;
}
```

-- PARTIAL ANSWER

I managed to create a hack, that makes multi-line UILabel visibile when scrolling bottom to up at some point:

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSArray *cells = [self.tableView visibleCells];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [cells objectAtIndex:0];
    [cell.superview bringSubviewToFront:cell];
}
```

I noticed that the part of the `UILabel` is covered by a row thats below of the `UILabel`s row and that hack makes it would be properly displayed. But it has a drawback, when scrolling slowly from bottom to top it generates a flicker when label is created (part of it should be visible before real creation of `UILabel`).

Comment: The UILabel is not part of the cell ,right?

Comment: Have you tried custom TableVieCell ?

Comment: Dinesh, yes, I'm using custom UITableViewCell for my purposes. Avi, UILabel IS a part of the cell - am I able to present some kind of a view in UITableView "manually"?

Comment: Post some of your code that you are Using (if possible with  some screen shot) That will be helpful in solving your problem

Comment: *"almost whole logic is in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath`"*. What?

Comment: vikingosegundo, I've added lines that reuses cells. Logic of creating cell height is: firstly, before reloading tableView create an array that contains all label heights for each section and then for each cell height is MAX(30.f, labelHeightForThatSection - 30*cellIndexPath.row) if it is last cell of section otherwise 30.f

Comment: It is obvious that you have an issue in your code. But you don't present most of the relevant parts. How do you expect us to help you?

Comment: I've added most of the code - if you think I need to add something more please write a comment

Comment: Just check where you're changing the height of the multiline label, pretty sure you're not resetting it at some point.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I NSLog frame of labelName after inserting text into it (in each first row of a section) and it gives me right values (numberOfLines and frame is correct) - if frame was incorrect the label wouldn't be multiline as it is on a screenshot (but it is clipped to first row UITableViewCell bounds). Can I force relayout of the label?

Answer (score 0):

Up mentioned answers are not solutions, but "hacks".
In the cell == nil block should be only the initialization.

You should not add any subviews in cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath.
The reason is simple: I will reuse a cell with some labels already added and add a new label.

Either use the default cell.textLabel, either create a subclass for UITableViewCell, with a

```
-(void)setData:(dictionary or string)object;
```

and in implementation just set the proper data to proper UI controls.

Add/create controls either in init method in the subclass, or in IB/Storyboard.

Call the dictionary or string should be picked in correspondence to indexPath, so you will always get proper data for proper cell at proper indexPath.

Comment: I am not adding any subviews, I have a custom UITableViewCell with an IB view, it has a few labels that each row consist of and a label named labelName that I want to be "multi-lined" along rows in that section. LabelName.text is not empty only for first row in each section. I am not sure what your answer gives me.

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellId = @"cellId";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    if (cell==nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];       
    }

    for (UIView *subview in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
    /// your UI on cell goes here
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure how this could be helpful? I suppose that removing all views that resides in contentView makes custom UITableView useless.

Comment: i guess the issue in your code is tableview reloading un necessarily.    for (UIView *subview in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }                                                                     this will fix it.

Comment: @CharanGiri: I also doubt that this will fix anything.

Comment: @CharanGiri it does mean that we are removing all subviews from cell and return that cell.Then what the use of that cell.And each time same thing are going to happen, performance will be degarde.

Comment: I never used CustomCell.. the above mentioned code by me i was using it from a long time i never got an issue with performance and reloading.

Comment: custom cells purpose is to avoid such nasty view hierarchy hacks. Just because you didn't realise your code has an issue doesn't mean it has no issue. @CharanGiri

Comment: @ vikingosegundo may i know the issue in performance please so that i can learn and use it.